# How do I use Google Apps Script to scrape a website for specific key words?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets

I found this code online, however it does not work when I "copy and paste" it into Google Apps Script:

https://webscraping.pro/scrape-google-app-script/

What changes must I make for it to work, or alternatively is there a straight-forward way to search for specific key words on a website and return the results in Google Sheets?

Comment: Be more specific, what kind of difficulties do you encountered, can you chare the copy of the script as you have done ? it can be there a lot of backslshes to clear.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I am not a coder (yet), consequently using specific requirements to learn from others. Above script returns errors with backslashes (like you say) and at the end of each line – adding a semicolon does not seem to work either.

Comment: You need to remove them all, along with other issues. The script is designed for Google Docs, not for spreadsheets. However I am testing it and the script cannot retrieve the information. may be an evolution of google's policy. I will continue to try to find another solution (if the page is not buit by javascript, because it will not be possible in that case to fetch the informations°. Hope somebody else has a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in a worksheet, then filter some unusable rows

```
function textOnly() {
  var url='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69148306/how-do-i-use-google-apps-script-to-scrape-a-website-for-specific-key-words?noredirect=1#comment122219344_69148306'
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  sh.clear()
  var data=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t)/gm," ").split('>')
  data.forEach(function (part){
    var text = part.split('<')[0]
    if (text.replace(/([ ]+)/gm,"")!='') {
      sh.appendRow([part.split('<')[0].replace(/([ ]{2,})/gm," ").replace(/(^ )/gm,"")])
    }
  })
}
```

You will then able to filter with your specific key words. To include these key words inside the script, assuming they are located in `keywords` range :

```
function textOnly() {
  var url='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69148306/how-do-i-use-google-apps-script-to-scrape-a-website-for-specific-key-words?noredirect=1#comment122219344_69148306'
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  sh.clear()
  var data=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t)/gm," ").split('>')
  var list = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('keywords').getValues().join('|').toLowerCase().split('|')
  var n=0
  data.forEach(function (part){
    var text = part.split('<')[0]
    var myText = part.split('<')[0].replace(/([ ]{2,})/gm," ").replace(/(^ )/gm,"")
    if (text.replace(/([ ]+)/gm,"")!='') {
      list.forEach(function (term){
        if (myText.toLowerCase().includes(term)){
          sh.appendRow([myText])
          n++
        }
      })
    }
  })
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(n+" item(s) found", "End of script !", 5);
}
```

Comment: Impressive! Your code even returns the metadata for an image, in the form: <"alt="This is an image">. Not that it matters, however some of the rows of text in Google Sheets have a 'space' before the text. Would you know why that is happening or know how to remove it through code? Also, in the if statement is there a line of code that would only push the text to Google Sheets when it includes one of a series of specific words, e.g. Questions, Tags and Users?

Comment: You can test by removing `.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t)/gm," ")` to prevent extra spaces. But sometimes you will get extra lines or tabulations. For the `if statment` you can filter the rows. Nevertheless I will work on it to find a solution.

Comment: Much appreciated, Mike. I have experimented with `.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t)/gm," ")` though unable to remove unwanted spaces. Some code that returns specific key words and removes a space at the start of any text added to Google Sheets would be ideal.

Comment: for removing space before texte `sh.appendRow([part.split('<')[0].replace(/([ ]{2,})/gm," ").replace(/(^ )/gm,"")])` I have updated my answer. For specific works I continue working on it.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I have tested your revised code on a bunch of websites and it is working perfectly. For specific words, I can pivot the data in Google Sheets and apply a filter however it is resource intensive.

Comment: I have added a new code to include keywords. However, I have a doubt about the effectiveness because if the html is as `name <span class='xxx'>Paul</span>` with `name` as keyword, you will not be able to fetch `Paul` which will be in another "item".

Comment: take a copy, everything works fine for me https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tEeceRO8CRWt3LuOvAt7R8FjxSRvfvGgoI-Kn-zgJfU/copy

Comment: Thanks Mike – I understand the caveat. The execution log returns the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValues' of null` for code `var list = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('keywords').getValues().join('|').toLowerCase().split('|')` as it is and when I change keywords or add text in inverted commas to `getValues()`. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you declare an area within your spreadsheet (in a separated tab) as `keywords`? Does the copy works as is for you?

Comment: Done now and works a treat! I need to insert `var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` and `SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[2])` to return the data on Sheet 2 – though cannot figure out where to do it successfully. If you can please help, or recommend a better way by say naming the sheet itself.

Comment: In my example, I define a tab as following `var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('items')` and then `sh.appendRow([myText])`

Comment: Got it! Very grateful for all your help, Mike.